# Counterexample for Bounded Convergence Theorem - Evaluating limits of Lebesgue Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show that if $f_n(x)=x\cdot\chi_{[0,n]}$, then $\{f_n\}$ is a counterexample for the Bounded Convergence Theorem. I started by showing:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x\cdot\chi_{[0,n]} = x $$
So $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=x$.

To show the Bounded Convergence Theorem is false in this case I want to show that:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n \neq \int_E f $$
However, I am not sure what to do next. I am thinking of solving them separately as
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E  x\cdot\chi_{[0,n]} $$
while the RHS becomes
$$ \int_E f = \int_E x $$

This is where I'm stuck though. Is there a choice of $E$ that makes these specifically easy to compute? Does it matter what I choose for $E$?

Comment: This does depend heavily on $E$. What if $E$ is a singleton or is a finite interval..?

Comment: The hypotheses for bounded convergence theorem are: $|f_n|\leq C$ and the measure space is finite. For a "counterexample," which one are you trying to show doesn't hold?

Comment: I thought this would be a counterexample because $\{f_n\}$ is not uniformly, pointwise bounded. That is, there exists no upper bound $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_n|\leq M$ for all $x$ and all $n$.

Comment: It depends though. Take Lebesgue measure. If your set $E$ is bounded (not just finite measure), then $f_n$ will be bounded and the bounded convergence theorem applies. As @CameronWilliams pointed out, it really depends what $E$ is. It also depends on what measure you are using.